# How to change items in an array using other items in the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to change array A to be like array B, making sure the hashed item becomes the before of any number of non hashed items, until the next hashed item

```
const A = [ '# test',
  'test',
  '# layouts',
  'main',
  'nav' ]

const B = ['test/test',
    'layouts/main',
    'layouts/nav' ]
```

Comment: Step 1, don't use a `const` for something you want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` for this, the accumulator should be an object containing two values, the first will be the results array and the other will be the current hash string to be used within `reduce` to generate the paths. Once `reduce` finishes its work we can store the `result` property of the accumulator into our result variable `B`:

```
const B = A.reduce((acc, str) => {                           // for each string in the array A
   if(str.indexOf("#") === 0) {                              // if the string is hashed one
      acc.currentHash = str.slice(2);                        // set the current hash to this string
   } else {                                                  // otherwise
      acc.result.push(acc.currentHash + "/" + str);          // use the current hash to generate the resulting string of the current string
   }
   return acc;
}, { result: [], currentHash: ""}).result;                   // once reduce finishes, use '.result' to access the result array of the accumulator
```

**Example:**

```js
const A = [ '# test', 'test', '# layouts', 'main', 'nav' ];

const B = A.reduce((acc, str) => {
   if(str.indexOf("#") === 0) {
      acc.currentHash = str.slice(2);
   } else {
      acc.result.push(acc.currentHash + "/" + str);
   }
   return acc;
}, { result: [], currentHash: ""}).result;

console.log(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred approach would be to map the array to the desired format and then filter out the extraneous markers.

```
const needle = '# ';
let directoryName = '';
const b = a.map((elem) => {
    if (elem.startsWith(needle)) {
        directoryName = elem.substring(needle.length);
        return;
    }
    return directoryName + '/' + elem;
}).filter(Boolean);
```

Note that I have optimized the code for readability. It will loop over the array twice, which is almost certainly fine, since the operations here are very fast. But if you have a huge array and need every bit of performance, Ibrahim's answer would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach you can take that utilizes `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Object.keys`

```js
function modify(a, delimiter) {
  const f = a.reduce((accum, el) => {
    var s = el.replace(/\s/g, '');
    if (s.charAt(0) === delimiter) {
      accum.pointer = s.substring(1);
      accum.data[accum.pointer] = [];
    } else {
      accum.data[accum.pointer].push(el);
    }
    return accum;
  }, {
    pointer: null,
    data: {}
  });

  return Object.keys(f.data).map(k => {
    var s = `${delimiter}${k}`
    var values = f.data[k];
    values.forEach(v => {
      s += `/${v}`
    });
    return s;
  });
}

const A = ['# test',
  'test',
  '# layouts',
  'main',
  'nav'
]

const B = modify(A, "#");
console.log(B);
```